# unix command for file seperation in two different folders

Tags: bash, macos, unix, mv

I am currently in `data` folder which has following files and folders

```
Folders:
    ISOLATE
    JUKEBOX

Files:
XXX-12-2345-67A-89T-1011-12.ab20.RenderBase20.ISOLATE.quantifier.txt
XXX-12-2345-67A-89T-1011-12.ab20.RenderBase20.JUKEBOX.quantifier.txt
XXX-24-2345-67A-89T-2022-24.ab10.RenderBase20.ISOLATE.quantifier.txt
XXX-24-2345-67A-89T-2022-24.ab10.RenderBase20.JUKEBOX.quantifier.txt
...
```

I want to put the files with .ISOLATE in Folder ISOLATE and .JUKEBOX ones in the JUKEBOX folder. How could I perform this task using terminal?

There are more than 12000 files, so I cannot really change the naming scheme.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What were your attempts trying to achieve this? Share your research efforts please.

Comment: I am not sure what your question meant? But how could this be achieved? Please answer the question. :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a community for requesting answers blindly. You need to show your clear efforts trying to achieve the solution and people can guide you through to reaching the solution.

Comment: @ParthRaghav the question may be more appropriate at ServerFault.

Comment: Hello @Kyle, thank you for informing me! Perhaps, it is better to inform than to reprimand people by simply down voting their questions! I will take care about this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to trying wildcards (bash pattern match or globs), which at some point will hit an upper limit based on the number of files, you can also use `find` and `xargs`:

```
find . -name '*.ISOLATE.*.txt' -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -IFILE mv FILE ./ISOLATE
find . -name '*.JUKEBOX.*.txt' -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -IFILE mv FILE ./JUKEBOX
```

Doing this won't be subject to the maximum number of command line arguments that the glob solution may hit.

They key things in the commands above are:

- `-maxdepth` 1 ensures that find won't keep looking into the `./ISOLOATE` or `./JUKEBOX` subdirectories
- `-print0` causes `find` to delimit the file names with a null byte rather than whitespace.  This protects you against files that have spaces or other special characters in their names.
- `-0` causes `xargs` to use the null byte delimiter rather than whitespace for the same reason
- `-IFILE` tells `xargs` to use the string `FILE` for each of the arguments.  Typically `xargs` puts the filenames on the right, which wouldn't work with the `mv` command.

I tested the approach with a small shell script:

```
touch XXX-12-2345-67A-89T-1011-12.ab20.RenderBase20.ISOLATE.quantifier.txt
touch XXX-12-2345-67A-89T-1011-12.ab20.RenderBase20.JUKEBOX.quantifier.txt
touch XXX-24-2345-67A-89T-2022-24.ab10.RenderBase20.ISOLATE.quantifier.txt
touch XXX-24-2345-67A-89T-2022-24.ab10.RenderBase20.JUKEBOX.quantifier.txt

mkdir ISOLATE
mkdir JUKEBOX

find . -name '*.ISOLATE.*.txt' -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -IFILE mv FILE ./ISOLATE
find . -name '*.JUKEBOX.*.txt' -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -IFILE mv FILE ./JUKEBOX
find .
```

Which outputs:

```
$ bash example.sh 
.
./example.sh
./ISOLATE
./ISOLATE/XXX-12-2345-67A-89T-1011-12.ab20.RenderBase20.ISOLATE.quantifier.txt
./ISOLATE/XXX-24-2345-67A-89T-2022-24.ab10.RenderBase20.ISOLATE.quantifier.txt
./JUKEBOX
./JUKEBOX/XXX-12-2345-67A-89T-1011-12.ab20.RenderBase20.JUKEBOX.quantifier.txt
./JUKEBOX/XXX-24-2345-67A-89T-2022-24.ab10.RenderBase20.JUKEBOX.quantifier.txt
```

Comment: Using `-I` option will execute `mv` for each file so this will be slower if # of files are huge. This `find + xargs` is equivalent of `for f in *.ISOLATE.*.txt; do mv "$f" ./ISOLATE; done`

Comment: @anubhava that is true, the -I will execute `mv` in a loop, I offered it to avoid the command line argument limit.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use wildcards:

```
mv *.ISOLATE.quantifier.txt ISOLATE/
mv *.JUKEBOX.quantifier.txt JUKEBOX/
```

If the number of files is too high, you might need to move them in smaller loads.

```
find -name '*.ISOLATE.quantifier.txt' -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} ISOLATE/ +
```

`-exec` with `+` should accumulate the command line arguments the same way as `xargs`, so you shouldn't overflow the maximal number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with huge # of files, you can use this `mv` with `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\0' *.ISOLATE.* | xargs -0 mv -t ISOLATE/
printf '%s\0' *.JUKEBOX.* | xargs -0 mv -t JUKEBOX/
```